# How to use CASE condition in WHERE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, case, where-in

I have a Spring boot app with custom queries.
I need to find all database rows according to condition - if `:myFlag` is `true`, field in database must be in a list (`:values` here), or *`null`*.
Can I use something like this:

```sql
select *
from test
where id<4
and (case
         when :myFlag then val in (:values)
         else val in (:values) or val is null
     end)
```

For example, if I have rows

```
id | val
1  | 1
2  | null
3  | 3
```

- When my `values = [1,3]`, `myFlag = true`, then the query must return rows with `id=1,3`.
- If `myFlag = false`, then I need to retrieve rows with `id=1,2,3`.

Comment: We don't use `CASE`in a `WHERE` clause usually, because a `CASE` expression creates values from expressions. Why create those values that me must then evaluate, when we can just check the expressions directly?

Comment: `CASE` is **not** a statement, and **not** exactly the same as an `if()` block where you choose which code branch to run. Rather, `CASE` is an **expression** that must have a value as the result. Furthermore, in SQL, true/false are not values in themselves, but rather the result of conditional/comparison expressions. Therefore, to use it with a `WHERE` clause, a  `CASE` expressions must have a result you can use with a comparison. For example, you can create a 1 or 0 result that is then compared with 1: `WHERE 1 = CASE ... END`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn In PostgreSQL, that statement isn't true. There's a [native `boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) type and `true`/`false` are values in themselves, (as much as a `1` is an integer value in itself). You can have a `case` statement that just produces that `boolean`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9K1l0hwq). I think Oracle 23c also finally added a `boolean`.

Comment: You're right that in Oracle, even 23c [with the `boolean` added](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-285FFCA8-390D-4FA9-9A51-47B84EF5F83A), you still can't toss the `case` around so freely: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MWpbz9BV). I'm guessing the SQL standard doesn't really regulate that specific thing, making most of the remark (not-this-)RDBMS-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a case here,

```sql
select ...
from ...
where ...
and (
  value in (:values)
  OR (:myFlag AND value IS NULL)
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I confused with the example. Edited it, now it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do pretty much exactly what you did, as long as you stick to the logic added in your later edit. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/lEDkEpab)

```
select * from test
where id<4
and (case
         when :myFlag then val in (:values)
         else val in (:values) or val is null
     end)
```

---

This:

> if `:myFlag` is `true`, field in database must be in a list (values here), or *`null`*.

means this:

```
select * from test
where id<4
and (case
         when :myFlag then val in (:values) or val is null
         else true
     end)
```

Meanwhile, these express a somewhat different logic:

> When my `values = [1,3]`, `myFlag = true`, then the query must return rows with `id = 1, 3`.

> If `myFlag = false`, then I need to retrieve rows with `id = 1, 2, 3`.

meaning this:

```
select * from test
where id<4
and (case
         when :myFlag then val in (:values)
         else val in (:values) or val is null
     end)
```

In the first paragraph, you **do** want the row `{id:2,val:null}` when `:myFlag` is `true`. The example you added later showed the opposite logic.

Funnily enough, [@JGH's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7635569/jgh) code you went with, expresses yet another variant:

```
select * from test
where id<4
and (case
         when :myFlag then val in (:values) or val is null
         else val in (:values)
     end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select * from t where not :myFlag or value in (1, 3)
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vt5Lw-ob).